# Select all tables values inside whereExist - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

I have to select few other columns as well instead of just top table columns. I have the code;

```
$records_all = DB::table('table1')
    ->whereExists(function($query) use ($date) {
           $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                 ->from('table2')
                 ->whereRaw('table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id')
                 ->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($date) {
                      $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                            ->from('table3')
                            ->whereRaw('table2.table2_id = table3.table2_id')
                            ->whereRaw("DATE(table3.date)='" . $date . "'");
                 });
  })
  ->orderBy('url')
  ->get();
```

This gives me records for table1 when required. but how to get anything from table2 or table3 ?

I am using laravel 4.2

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ->from('table2')->select('table2.table2_id','table2.name')

Comment: Now worked, same results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change DB::raw(1) to specific column you need and separate column by comma

```
$records_all = DB::table(DB::raw('table1, table2, table3'))
    ->select('table1.*','table2.table2_id','table3.table3_id')
    ->whereExists(function($query) use ($date) {
        $query->from('table2')
        ->whereRaw('table2.table1_id = table1.table1_id')
        ->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($date) {
            $query->from('table3')
            ->whereRaw('table2.table2_id = table3.table2_id')
            ->whereRaw("DATE(table3.date)='" . $date . "'");
        });
    })
    ->orderBy('url')
    ->get();
```

to get print last executed query just after above statement

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
print_r($last_query);exit;
```

Comment: Its now working @kamlesh.bar , still returning only 1st table records

Comment: whats error you are getting? for log last executed query use this   $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
print_r($last_query);exit;

Comment: logged the last query, ran it directly to the database, still only returning table1 records.

Comment: Not working... error on `->select('table1.*','table2.table2_id','table3.table3_id')`  Error:  `1054 Unknown column 'table2.table2_id'...` @kamlesh.bar

Comment: ohh dear i am making too many error DB::table(DB::raw('table1, table2, table3')).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76041/discussion-between-fahad-and-kamlesh-bar).